# ArgumentError (cannot parse Cookie header: invalid %-encoding (Req%201008%20-

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, encoding, jruby

In my rails app, when I am using some non uni-code chars like

côme sa va?
Cómo estás?
Représenter
代表
પ્રતિનિધિત્વ
要求
Požádat
అభ్యర్థించవచ్చు

my app seems to be crashing with the following error:

```
Started GET "/requests/1008" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-22 18:00:47 +0530
ArgumentError (cannot parse Cookie header: invalid %-encoding (Req%201008%20-  %20%u0AAA%u0ACD%u0AB0%u0AA4%u0ABF%u0AA8%u0ABF%u0AA7%u0ABF%u0AA4%u0ACD%u0AB5*http://127.0.0.1:3000/requests/1008)):
```

Please Let me know if any one has any idea on this issue.

Thanks,
Dean.

Comment: Check out this issue at the Rack github repo: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/337 Lots of information there.. you aren't alone

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is clear cookies for this particular site (localhost in your case).

Something set incorrectly cookie.